# How to add a type node after a particular type node within a navigation node in the Explorer Tree in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In the backoffice, in the explorer tree, we have Users navigation within which we have Customer. I want to add another node after Customer node. How can this be done? I have thought of the following code, but I'm not sure, this would work. Please can any one guide me.

```
     <context component="explorer-tree" module="trainingbackoffice" merge-by="module">
         <n:explorer-tree xmlns:n="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/explorertree">
           <n:navigation-node id="hmc_treenode_user">
              <n:type-node code="MyCustomNode" id="my_node"/>
           </n:navigation-node>
         </n:explorer-tree>
     </context>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **position** attribute for this. Just specify the position you want your custom item to be (0 based index)

Example to put your my_node as the third item in that list

```
 <context component="explorer-tree" module="trainingbackoffice" merge-by="module">
     <n:explorer-tree xmlns:n="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/explorertree">
       <n:navigation-node id="hmc_treenode_user">
          <n:type-node code="MyCustomNode" id="my_node" position="2"/>
       </n:navigation-node>
     </n:explorer-tree>
 </context>
```